# HTML text input, no numeric

Tags: html, validation

I have an HTML5 text field for given name (first name).

```
<input name="name" id="name" autocompletetype="given-name"  type="text" alt="" maxlength="16" required/>
```

Some users put password here. Thus I want to prevent some of them by not allowing numbers. How I'll accomplish this? So, I want only English and Turkish letters plus `-` and `'` for any case, oh and these â,Â,ê.. for any case. Better way is not to allow numbers I guess but is there such way?

Comment: Use javascript key events to check if the character typed is a number.

Comment: You have a serious UX problem if your users are entering passwords in the firstname field. Please consider fixing *that* instead of disallowing numbers in the first name field (or how else is "Edward the 2nd von Munchhausen" going to register? :D)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you can use javascript/jQuery.

Please note that I am unsure if the letter sequence below covers only turkish letters/all turkish letters. However, it is a pretty exhaustive list of letters used in various languages.

Then:

```
     $('#name').on('change', function(){
            if(/^[a-zA-Z\- ’'‘ÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ]$/.test($(this).val())){
                $(this).removeClass('invalidField');
                $(this).addClass('validField');
          } else {
                $(this).addClass('invalidField');
                $(this).removeClass('validField');
          }
      });
```

And then use CSS to mark fields valid/invalid. (A red border for invalid fields for instance)